# Unignored a Git folder; now cannot pull at other site

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repo with a foo/ directory committed. I had ignored the *foo/* directory again after committing, but recently un-ignored it (removing the entry from the gitignore file at site 1, committing the contents). I just tried to pull this change down at site 2 but I'm being told:

`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by the merge:`

And then a list of files in *foo/*. I'm guessing these files were made in *foo* after gitignoring. I've tried resetting the folder state but that isn't working - is this because reset won't un-create files? Have I got myself tangled here or is there an easy way to get myself fetch/merging again at site 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current ignored files in `foo/` are not important, you can just `rm -rf foo/` and then `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ git checkout -f another-branch
```

This will force git to go ahead and overwrite the files. Switch to the other branch and then  fix the issue